# Any way to get the calling class on static functions in Swift?

Tags: swift

The question is better explained in code:

```
class A {
     class func thefunc() -> String {

        /* Can I here know if thefunc was called using
            A.thefunc() or
            B.thefunc()?
        */

        return "A" /* or "B"= */
    }
}

class B: A {

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `self` in a static method to refer to the type (as compared to the *instance* for using `self` in an instance method)

```
class A {
    class func thefunc() -> A.Type {
        return self
    }
}

class B: A { }

let metaTypeA = A.thefunc() // A.Type
let metaTypeB = B.thefunc() // B.Type
```

Similarly, you can use runtime introspection, specifically the `subjectType` property of the `Mirror` representation of `self`.

> **Instance Variables**
>
> ...
>
> `var subjectType: Any.Type`
>
> The static type of the subject being reflected.

From [the swiftdoc.org reference of `Mirror` structure](http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Mirror/).

E.g.:

```
class A {
    class func thefunc() {
        print(Mirror(reflecting: self).subjectType)
    }
}

class B: A { }

A.thefunc() // A.Type
B.thefunc() // B.Type
```

Alternatively, if you needn't actually make use of the meta-type (just differ between the "static caller"), you could use the `String` representation of `self`.

```
class A {
    class func thefunc() -> String {
        return String(self)
    }
}

class B: A { }

print(A.thefunc()) // A
print(B.thefunc()) // B
```